# Iframe not writing from dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, drop-down-menu, multiple-instances

I have had a look all over the web for answers but can't find anything specific enough to help - the last thing I found was a document.write function but also how "bad practice" it is. I have a drop down that changes markers on a google map, I want the same selection to pull in an iframe table - should be simple but the below only pulls the first iframe regardless - I don't think my search-string is correct - someone please fix my code I have spent weeks on this!

```
      <label class="layer-wizard-search-label">
    Underground Line
    <select id="search-string_0" onchange="changeMap_0(this.value)" >
      <option value="--Select--">--Select--</option>
      <option value="Bakerloo">Bakerloo</option>
      <option value="Central">Central</option>
      <option value="Circle">Circle</option>
      </select>
  </label> 

    <script type = "text/javascript">
    var res = document.getElementById("search-string_0");

if (res="Bakerloo") {
document.write('<iframe  width="700" height="900" scrolling="yes" frameborder="no" src="https://www.google.com/fusiontables/embedviz?viz=GVIZ&amp;t=TABLE&amp;q=select+col1%2C+col5%2C+col6%2C+col9%2C+col10%2C+col7+from+1fsnkGRq7SphzxmrnbnYBP1MaAMnDQq-FvUb6TSCl&amp;containerId=googft-gviz-canvas"></iframe>');
} else if (res="Central"){
document.write('<iframe  width="700" height="900" scrolling="yes" frameborder="no" src="https://www.google.com/fusiontables/embedviz?viz=GVIZ&amp;t=TABLE&amp;q=select+col1%2C+col5%2C+col6%2C+col9%2C+col10%2C+col7+from+1IH846oqs0nUdFWW4td_OKUF4R3cQQriFzR2zLBx5&amp;containerId=googft-gviz-canvas"></iframe>');
} else {
document.write('<iframe  width="700" height="900" scrolling="yes" frameborder="no" src="https://www.google.com/fusiontables/embedviz?viz=GVIZ&amp;t=TABLE&amp;q=select+col1%2C+col5%2C+col6%2C+col9%2C+col10%2C+col7+from+1QwZaLH0v420t9Q9HXmc7pZjZU25_orToPhiMQBN-&amp;containerId=googft-gviz-canvas"></iframe>');
}

</script>
```

Comment: Nuts - didn't work... any more ideas - I hoped it was that simple! Thanks

Comment: You should put it in a function-handler

Comment: Are you able to provide a link for the example?

Comment: not sure about a link - the iframe are public so should work anywhere, by function-handler do you mean another function e.g. below? onchange="changeMap_0(this.value);result()"

Comment: I'm learning so sorry if I ask stupid questions!